# Mysterious cable in old Jetta 2006

Tags: vw, jetta

While I was dissasembling interiors of my old VW Jetta to paint the body, I stumbled across quite an interesting cable, close to the left upper corner of a front glass that just ends.

Here are a few photos:
[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what is it?

Comment: Perhaps a (possibly coaxial) cable that ran from the dash area up to a radio antenna, located above the middle of the rear glass.

Comment: **Two** interesting cables – neither is original fit. My guess is that it may have been a taxi in its former life, which may have had two extra radios: CB to talk to other drivers and operator's radio for jobs.

Comment: ... and with cell phone tech that's all gone to the wind... they use an app for job bookings, and Whatsapp for driver chat.

Answer (score 1):

This here:

[image]

Leads me to believe it's NOT original.  No auto manufacturer would run a wire or tube "naked" across a sharp sheet metal edge like this.  It's a failure just waiting to happen.

My guess is that the previous owner added a wire to power a radar detector or dashcam and this is all that remains of it since they cut the end off.

Comment: I thought the OP was asking about the brown cable, the one that "just ends" in the photo. You're right about the black one...no manufacturer would route a cable in that fashion.

Comment: Or a CB radio aerial.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica  I didn't even notice the brown one since the black one is so obvious.  But I think the answer is the same for either of them, something added aftermarket that is no longer installed.

Comment: Unlike the black one (with which I agree with you), the brown one does look factory installed, though it terminates rather weirdly. I believe the brown one is what the OP is asking about, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and suggest the brown wire/tube is the aerial for your radio. Since it terminates weirdly, appears factory installed, and I'm not seeing a separate aerial on pictures I've looked at, that's what's leading me to believe it's what it is.